# Angular - get one subscription from multiple

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I need to have only latest subscription from multiple.

When my `FormControl` value changes, I need to have only latest value after user finished typing. Here is my code -

```
let control = this.register.controls['email'];
control.valueChanges.debounceTime(300).pipe(take(1)).subscribe(newValue => {
  console.log(newValue);
})
```

But it returns multiple `Subscriptions`. How can I get latest one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with `withLatestFrom` or `combineLatest`. But recommended way is to use `withLatestFrom`

- `take(1)` will take only the first value and its stops observing.

  ```
  this.formGroup.get('nom').valueChanges
  .pipe(
    debounceTime(300),
    // combineLatest()
    withLatestFrom()
  ).subscribe(newValue => {
    console.log(newValue);
  });
  ```

Checkout: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-formcontrol-example-seyfto

Comment: probably also a good idea to stick a `distinctUntilChanged` after the debouce in the pipe stream to prevent event firing if user types and then immediately undoes this change.

Comment: getting latest value but `subscribe` callback triggers for multiple times with same value.

Comment: let's say, if I type five characters `subscribe` callback triggers for 5 times

Comment: If you want to get only the last value you need trigger and close event on blur

Comment: I am getting the last value, but the issue is within `subscribe` callback I have to send API request. So upon customizing field text, multiple duplicate API requests sent.

Comment: Also, I am executing the code in `custom validator`

Comment: As I triggered the `subscription` in `custom validator` that's why with changing value it returned multiple subscriptions. I changed the logic and works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [withlatestfrom](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/withlatestfrom.html)

```
let control = this.register.controls['email'];
control.valueChanges.debounceTime(300).pipe(withLastestForm(control.valueChanges)).subscribe(newValue => {
  console.log(newValue);
})
```

Change this code to your accordingly